# How can I center text just above the corresponding image?

Tags: html, css

I have two images and two links. The problem is that the links come down of image. Like in the pictures

```css
.motto {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}


/*
.choiceImage a {
    display: contents;
}*/

.choiceImage {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 790px;
  height: 600px;
}

.choiceImage img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.choiceImage div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.choiceImage p {
  background-color: beige;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.choiceImage img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="choiceImage">
  <div>
    <p>I'm looking for..</p>
    <p>I offer something..</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><img alt="want something" src="image/want-something.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img alt="offer something" src="image/offer-something.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I can fix that with `display:context;` for the link, but I want another answer for this problem.

[image: This image shows you the problem, without display:context;]

Comment: you can add `display: block` to the link, `.choiceImage a {}`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to align things horizontally, but they usually involve putting them inside container elements. Have you tried using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or CSS grid? A little research into layout strategies should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The `display: contents` is expected to inherit from its grandparent *choiceimage* which is not set here so by default it is set to `display: block`.

Set the styles for the links like this:

```
.choiceImage a {
display: inline-block; 
}
```

But I highly recommend using FlexBox, it is really efficient for lay-outing and also for responsive development.

Comment: I will go for this solution.